# What is causing my application to fail to start?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-billing

im getting an error when opening my application
Here is the error

```
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165): java.lang.NullPointerException
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at    android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1097)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1114)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
        10-22 11:06:08.137: E/AndroidRuntime(25165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the manifest thread

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/schoolbus"
    android:label="The Back To School Zone" >



    <!--*************************************************  -->
    <!--*************************************************  -->
    <!--******  starting the ACTIVITIES classes  ********  -->
    <!--*************************************************  -->
    <!--*************************************************  -->





    <activity
        android:name=".mainMenu"
        android:label="The Back To School Zone"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">

     </activity>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

or is it the billing permissions that is causing the thread to fail? I cant seem to figure out why this is not launching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that yoyu have not fully qualified the name of your launching Activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".mainMenu"
```

Android would normally pick the package up from the Manifest element, but you didn't post that so it's hard to be 100% sure. But from what you have posted it would seem it has nothing to do with Admob.